# Delete Google Maps GMSMarker on Long Press

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, maps

I'm pretty new to working with the google maps api. I'm trying to give the user the option to delete a marker from the map by pressing and holding on the marker. I know that google maps has a built in function for markerTapped as well as didLongPressOnInfoWindow, but I could not seem to find a way to detect a long press on the marker itself.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to implement a long press gesture recognizer on the marker itself? Or if perhaps there's a more intuitive way to delete a marker from a map than long pressing the marker?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on what your markers are for, it may be more intuitive to use a custom view for your markers' info windows and have a button on the custom view that the user can tap to remove the marker. You could also have a button somewhere on the UI that removes the selected marker when the button is tapped (some kind of delete button). The most intuitive way to delete a marker is partly personal preference and partly what the marker is marking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Remove a Marker**

> In Swift 3

```
//Press on Button Forcefully for long time
let pressHold = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pressHolding(sender:))
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(pressHold)

//Handle in pressHolding Function
func pressHolding(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
    {
        //Here you can do your task like delete or edit on market etc:-
    }
}

//This is long Press function:-
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
   //Here handle your long press on map marker like:-
   let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683, longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 6)
   let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
   mapView.clear()
}
```

[Here you can find Objective-C and Swift All available Function of Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#remove_a_marker)

Hope it will help you a lot.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm asking how to detect a long press on a marker, not how to remove it from the map.

Comment: @ThatOneGuy did you found a way to achieve the long press on the marker?